# JqGrid pager button moves on hover

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I wanted to remove this hover effect for buttons, instead i want to change the back color. But couldn't find any possible css which do that.

Update: I meant the navGrid/inlineNav buttons. "Move" - I meant it kinda look like pixel shift. I added some css to override the existing theme for the grid. If i remove that, the grid works fine. But with my css whenever i hover on any button, it moves to 1 or 2 px left. I'm sure it has something to do with my added CSS. But can't find which causing this issue.

Any helps is appriciated.

Comment: Could you describe more clear what you want? Which "pager button" you mean? Do you mean navigator buttons added by `navGrid` or `inlineNav`? Which "move" effects on hovering you mean? Probably you have some CSS problems?

Comment: Yes, I meant the navGrid/inlineNav buttons. "Move" - I meant it kinda look like pixel shift.

Comment: Look at any demo like [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage1.htm). Do you see any "Move" effect on hovering? It you do have such effect you should post the demo which can be used to reproduce your problem because the problem should exist in your implementation only. I suppose that you have some CSS conflict, but one can't say which one without to see the demo.

Comment: I can't show you a demo cause we haven't host the code yet. but here is our css that override the existing theme of jqgrid - http://pastebin.com/ASrVYxye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not see full CSS which you use because I don't had all background images which you use. Nevertheless I hope that I could find out the reason of your problem.

In the CSS which you use there are

```css
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus
{
    color: #444444;
    border: 0 none;
}
```

setting. Changing of the border to 0 on hovering following to moving of the icons. If you don't need the border you can set for example the `border-color` to `transparent` instead:

```css
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus
{
    color: #444444;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Precisely that property was the issue. :)